# TCP: Redundant checksum avoidance specification

Tags: tcp, checksum

TCP provides a mechanism to [change the checksum scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1146#appendix-I) used by the two parties in a TCP session. There are four allowed checksum schemes according to [this table](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tcp-parameters/tcp-parameters.xml#tcp-parameters-2), the last being "Redundant Checksum Avoidance".

As far as I understand from [this Q&A](ftp://ftp.ucsd.edu/pub/csl/fastnet/faq.txt), the Redundant Checksum Avoidance scheme essentially removes the checksum. Is the checksum then required to be all 0s? Is the checksum altogether removed?

The only RFC covering the [change the checksum scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1146#appendix-I) I found does not cover the Redundant Checksum Avoidance scheme. Where can I find an RFC discussing it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MV see http://serverfault.com/questions/454886/is-the-tcp-checksum-over-the-payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest protocol, based on your specifications is: [DCCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCCP) as defined by [RFC 4336](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4336). The RFC1146 you mentioned is obsoleted by [RFC6247](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6247). See also: [Wikipedia: Comparison of transport-layer protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer#Comparison_of_transport-layer_protocols)

Comment: Thanks. I'm stuck with TCP. See my comment in the question mdpc linked for a description what I want to do.